# Converted comments don't keep their "great comment" flags

Tags: bug, status-declined, moderator-tools, comment-voting, convert-to-comment

When a moderator converts an answer to a comment all comments to this answer can also be moved with it.

However, in doing this any "great comment" flags are cleared from the migrated comments.  This should be changed so that the "great comment" flags are preserved.

Comment: I was just going to open the same post. This shouldn't be so difficult to implement and avoids "punishing" commentators by clearing their comment up-votes (which are used to get badges after all).

Answer (score 2):

<s>Answer upvotes do not equal comment upvotes; I don't think it's correct to link the two.</s>

If anything, we will remove the dubious "ability" to convert comments on an answer to comments themselves.

I almost never see a need to convert sub-comments when converting an answer to a comment, so in that case this request seems almost irrelevant to me. In fact I don't think I have *ever* converted the comments on an answer along with the answer, when converting an answer to a comment.

Comment: He was specifically talking about the commont votes on the comments that follow the answer, not the votes on the answer itself.  In other words, the answer becomes a comment, and the comments that were on that answer are moved to the question (in some cases).  In those cases that they are, comment votes on moved comments should be retained.

Comment: @m.t I almost never see a need to convert sub-comments when converting an answer to a comment, so in that case this request seems almost irrelevant to me. In fact I don't think I have *ever* converted the comments on an answer along with the answer, when converting an answer to a comment.

Comment: I do it when user A posts an answer, new user B requests clarification in an answer, and user A actually sees the request and replies to it in a comment.