# Transfer upvotes when converting answer to comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answers converted to comments should retain upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87489/answers-converted-to-comments-should-retain-upvotes)
>   [Converted comments don't keep their “great comment” flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92955/converted-comments-dont-keep-their-great-comment-flags)

Moderators have the ability to [convert answers to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/convert-to-comment) when necessary. It would be nice if upvotes on the answer were automatically transferred as upvotes on the comment: sometimes, a person will post an answer which raises a very important, relevant point, but isn't an answer. In those cases, it would be nice for the information to still be highlighted. If a comment thread is over 5 long, some comments aren't shown, so giving the comment the votes from the answer it came from would be useful.

**For example:** [This answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/229362/fixing-bent-pins-on-a-cpu/229365#229365) (now [a comment](https://superuser.com/users/61182/jay-booney), for those with <10k) provided some useful advice: "be careful not to bend the pin too many times, they turn brittle quickly and snap". Should it have ever been an answer? Probably not, but the user *was* providing helpful information, and at the time had <50 rep, so he couldn't answer. **The point here is that if an answer should be a comment and it has a lot of upvotes, it's probably important in *some* way.**

Because comments do not have such a thing as a "downvote", this could perhaps only be applied to comments with no downvotes, or the total score (`up - down`) could be used. To prevent users from re-voting on the comment, anybody who had already voted for the answer would see the UI as if they had already upvoted it. Prior downvoters would retain the ability to vote it back up.

Based on some of the comments and related answers suggested below, I would also propose that this only be applied when the comment has a total score of at least 5, indicating that it was actually useful in some way. Again, this is so that potentially important information doesn't get burried, even if it shouldn't have been an answer in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converted comments don't keep their "great comment" flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92955/converted-comments-dont-keep-their-great-comment-flags) or perhaps better: [converting answer upvotes to comment upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87489/answers-converted-to-comments-should-retain-upvotes)

Comment: Though it's not really duplicate, what Jeff said applies to this case as well: "Answer upvotes do not equal comment upvotes; I don't think it's correct to link the two" so I can't see this implemented any time soon.

Answer (score 6):

Answer upvotes do not equal comment upvotes; I don't think it's correct to link the two.

Comment: This is true.  However, the set of reasons for which I will upvote a question is a subset of the set of reasons for which I will upvote a comment.  I'll upvote a question is helpful and/or insightful.  I'll upvote a comment if it either of these, or funny (clever, ironic, etc).

Comment: It's the part after "or.." which is problematic.

Comment: Jeff, @Wont's point is that if he would upvote the answer, he would also upvote it as a comment, in (nearly) all cases, but there are also cases where he would upvote the comment and _not_ the answer. So the comment always gets the upvote.

Comment: @nhink but comment votes have a completely different meaning than post votes. For example a post answer downvote is -1 to you, and -2 to the poster, whereas downvotes don't even exist on comments.