# Comment upvotes not carried over when converting answer to comment

Tags: discussion, comment-voting, convert-to-comment

I know it's already been covered that [Answer upvotes are not the same as Comment upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101300/147335), but suppose the following situation occurs:

```
Useful answer that should have been a comment
  - Useful comment with upvotes
```

Naturally, the answer gets converted to a comment. In the process, I check the box that says "move comments" because they're useful and should be kept. But the upvotes on that comment, which are genuine and deserved, don't get carried over.

So if the answer had upvotes, it doesn't get to keep those. (And really, it shouldn't have had them if our methodology says it should be a comment.) But the comment was a good comment and deserved the upvotes it received. Shouldn't it retain the votes that IT has? Sure, AnswerVotes != CommentVotes, but shouldn't CommentVotes == CommentVotes?

Am I missing something here? Is this an oversight or is it intentional?

Comment: I totally agree. however, something tells me that implementing the idea may be somewhat difficult. But certainly it's fair and just to carry over upvotes

Comment: Since comments are second-class citizens and the votes on them only help to ensure that the comment appears when there are some hidden, does it matter that much?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with carrying them over. By moving the comments to another post, you're injecting them into an existing conversation with its own votes and comment sorting. I think it makes sense to reset the counts to better integrate them into the conversation that was already there.

Comment: @animuson If the answer being converted had 3 great comments (and lets say 3 others that were carried over to provide context for the great comments) while the answer had 1 or 0 comments, then you could make the case that THOSE comments are injecting themselves instead of the other way around. After all, they're comments that should have been in that original 'conversation' all along.

Comment: I don't believe "should have" is a valid argument for that, though. The fact is they *weren't*.

Comment: By that logic, if a spam post goes a few hours without being noticed by moderators or users... well sure it "should have" been deleted, but the fact is it *wasn't* so we'll do nothing about it.

Comment: The situations are nowhere near comparable.

Comment: Then think of it in terms of signal to noise: keeping the comment votes increases signal on a channel that can be incredibly noisy.